# How to change color of FloatingActionButton in a PageView widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using a `PageView` widget in the body of my app. Every `PageView` child has a specific `SliverAppBar` color and I want the `FloatingActionButton` to have the same color as the `SliverAppBar`, but I have no idea how to create this. Because the only differece between pages is the content and the color, I created a custom Widget in a different file.

Following is a simplified version of my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  Color color;

  Scaffold(
    body: PageView(
      children: [
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            )
          ],
        ),
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      backgroundColor: color,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your Colors in a Color list and in `onPageChanged` method change the index of color for `flotingActionButton` with `setState` method in `Stateful` widget:

```
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  int _index = 0;
  List<Color> pagesColor = [Colors.blue, Colors.green];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: PageView(
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              )
            ],
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: pagesColor.elementAt(_index),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, because you placed your in _Test2State, when you build your widget, _index will always be 0 again.

Comment: You're welcome. the index become 0 only when the class created. After that it will not be 0 because I defined it  before build method.. In setState method just rebuild the build method not the fields before build method.

Comment: Oow, it didn't work for me. I'm pretty new to Flutter so there could be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will do your work:
Enjoy...!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
Color color;

Scaffold(
body: PageView(
  onPageChanged: (val){
  if(val == 0)
  {
    color = Colors.blue;
    setState(() {});
   }
   else if(val == 1){
   color = Colors.green;
   setState(() {});       
    }
    }
  children: [
    CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        )
      ],
    ),
    CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  backgroundColor: color,
),
);
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible the onPageChanged should be placed in the PageView and in the children list?

Comment: sorry my mistake, yes it will be placed in the pageView not the children. Have updated the code above :)

Comment: and don't forgot to change to class to statefull if its stateless for setState to work

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! It didn't work directly as you said so I will create my own answer, but the onPageChanged did it!